# Embed xsl into an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt, embed

I'm trying to embed an xsl into a XML file.  The reason for doing this is to create a single file that could be moved to different computers, this would prevent the need to move the xsl file.

The xsl file is creating a table and grabbing a test step from the xml and whether it passed or failed, pretty simple.
The issue I'm having, I think, is that the xsl has javascript and its being displayed when the xml is loaded in IE.

When I load the xml file with IE, the javascript is displayed above the table and below the table the xml is displayed.

Here is how my document is laid-out :

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
]>

<doc>    

<xsl:stylesheet id="4.1.0" 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:user="http://www.ni.com/TestStand" 
    xmlns:vb_user="http://www.ni.com/TestStand/" >

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">

    <msxsl:script language="vbscript" implements-prefix="vb_user">
        option explicit
        'This function will return the localized decimal point for a decimal number
        Function GetLocalizedDecimalPoint ()
            dim lDecPoint
            lDecPoint = Mid(CStr(1.1),2,1)
            GetLocalizedDecimalPoint = lDecPoint
        End Function
    </msxsl:script>
    <msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user"><![CDATA[
        // This style sheet will not show tables instead of graphs for arrays of values if 
        // 1. TSGraph control is not installed on the machine
        // 2. Using the stylesheet in windows XP SP2. Security settings prevent stylesheets from creatign the GraphControl using scripting. 
        //     Refer to the TestStand Readme for more information.

//more javascript functions
//code to build table and insert data from the xml

</xsl:stylesheet>

<Reports>
<Report Type='UUT' Title='UUT Report' Link='-1-2008-12-3-10-46-52-713' UUTResult='Failed' StepCount='51'>

// rest of xml

</Report>

</Reports>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 11):

[**Although the W3C XSLT Spec supports embedding an XSLT stylesheet**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Embedding-Stylesheets) into an XML document, it seems that IE and Firefox do not support this.

**UPDATE**: As per the comment by Robert Niestroj, years later, in Oct.  2014, this works in FireFox 33.

**However, there is a good alternative: embed the XML document into the XSLT stylesheet**.

Below is an example.

**An XSLT stylesheet containing an embedded XML document**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myEmbedded.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vEmbDoc">
        <doc>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <para id="foo">Hello I am foo</para>
            </body>
        </doc>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="para">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xsl:template"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When tis file is opened in IE, the wanted result is displayed by the browser:

## Hello I am foo

**Do note**, that it is necessary to include templates that ignore most of the XSLT instructions (in this case we are ignoring any `<xsl:template>` by simply having no template body.

Comment: Important note for when you're embedding a document within a style sheet like this - the filename is encoded in the first line of the style sheet. That means that if you rename the file, the document will no longer parse.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheet embedding is possible for most browsers but IE.
Find the reference to a description and example in the posting below.

IE6/7/8 do not support embedded stylesheets by default.

You may want to use the workaround enabling IE to process embedded stylesheets from here:

http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201001/msg00390.html

Answer (score 0):

Because your stylesheet makes use of msxsl the previous technique for anabling stylesheet embedding for IE browsers should be fine for you.

If you want stylesheet embedding which works for all browsers you might want to use technique [support of stylesheet embedding for ALL browsers](http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/embedded-xslt-77694.html#post2420740).

Comment: Did you want to edit your previous answer with this information? I can do that for you. Did you lose your connection to your previous account? Click the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page and tell the team.