# How to work with an embedded XML and XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an embedded file containing both XML and XSL. The test is based on ["XML and XSL in one file"](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/onefile.html) on dpawson.co.uk. The source looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
<xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- any xsl:import elements -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
  <!-- rest of your stylesheet -->
</xsl:stylesheet>

<!-- rest of your XML document -->
</doc>
```

Originally I have made a working XML and XSL file. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xsl"?>
<Report>
    <ReportFor>Test Data</ReportFor>
    <CreationTime>2009-07-29 05:37:14</CreationTime>
</Report>
```

And the `data.xsl` file looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Report/ReportFor" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Report/CreationTime"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on these I'm trying to create an embedded XML file containing both XML and XSL.

Currently this file looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
<xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- any xsl:import elements -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
  <!-- rest of your stylesheet -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Report/ReportFor" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Report/CreationTime"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<!-- rest of your XML document -->
<Report>
    <ReportFor>Test Data</ReportFor>
    <CreationTime>2009-07-29 05:37:14</CreationTime>
</Report>

</doc>
```

The problem with this document is that the `<xsl:value-of>` does not retrieve the data represented in the XML section. How is it possible for `<xsl:value-of>` to recognize the embedded data? Is some special syntax needed?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360628/embed-xsl-into-an-xml-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360628/embed-xsl-into-an-xml-file)

Comment: I was about to post the "embed the XML in the XSL" suggestion, but since that has already been answered: A link is better.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the doc element in your template match attribute. Try this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/doc">
   <xsl:value-of select="Report/ReportFor" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to use the "." operator to get the value?

```
 <xsl:value-of select="Report/ReportFor/."/>
```