# How to Embed XSL into XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for a solution to embed XSL into XML so there is only 1 XML file that is sent to the browser. I tried the solution proposed by Dimitre Novatchev here: [Embed xsl into an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360628/embed-xsl-into-an-xml-file/15121012#15121012)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    <xsl:variable name="vEmbDoc">
    <doc>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <para id="foo">Hello I am foo</para>
        </body>
    </doc>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="para">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xsl:template"/></xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that with this solution I can not find a way to include style element inside the head. Seems like in the proposed solution head and body tags do not have any effect since the browser will add them automatically during parsing and the solution works even without having those tags included.

So the question is: How to include style element in the head in the above mentioned solution that will look like this:

```
<head><style>body {font-size:10pt;padding:20pt} </style></head>
```

Comment: So, what is the exact wanted result? Please, *edit* the question and provide this important, missing information.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thank you for replying. I would like to include style element in the head like this: 
<head>
<style>
body {font-size:10pt;padding:20pt}
...
</style>
</head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XML document**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myEmbedded.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vEmbDoc">
        <doc>
            <head>
              <style>body {font-size:10pt;padding:20pt}</style>
              </head>
            <body>
                <para id="foo">Hello I am foo</para>
            </body>
        </doc>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="para">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="doc">
  <html>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:template"/>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:*">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**contains an XSLT stylesheet. The starting PI instructs the browser to apply this stylesheet on itself**.

**The transformation thus specified, produces the wanted result**:

```
    <html>

   <head xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

              <style>body {font-size:10pt;padding:20pt}</style>
              </head>

   <body xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <h1>Hello I am foo</h1>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to accept the answer! This is my first question in this forum so I was looking for a button that says "Accept" but couldn't find it. It never crossed my mind that this check-mark is not just a picture :)